# Mapping column names with EntityFramwork.BulkInsert

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, bulkinsert

We needed a bulk add feature for EF6 DBFirst, for that I tried to download a package from

> https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Which is supposedly quite efficient. but the problem that I face is, is that it is mixing up all the column values

so for example my column values are

A - B - C - D

1....2....3....4

it inserts data in wrong order, like 3....2....4....1 or something. and then later on it breaks the unique constraint.

I cant figure out why it does that. has anyone any experience with this package as to if we can provide any mapping of any sort ?

Answer (score 1):

Second [this](https://praneethmoka.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/problem-with-bulk-insert-using-entity-framework/) article:

> The order of the properties in your entity class should be the same as the order of the columns in your database table.

Can you try that in your project?